# C# UWP how to get mapi namespace

Tags: c#, uwp, outlook

I need to send a mail with Attachments. I see that this is possible with MAPI. But how can i get this Namespace in UWP?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: What did you mean about 'MAPI'? Did you want some APIs to send email in UWP?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [EmailManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager#Windows_ApplicationModel_Email_EmailManager_ShowComposeNewEmailAsync_Windows_ApplicationModel_Email_EmailMessage_) for UWP. It allows an application to launch the email application with a new message displayed. See [Sending email attachments via UWP EmailManager not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053358/sending-email-attachments-via-uwp-emailmanager-not-working) for the sample code.